# How to change all highlighted words in jTextPane to the word given in jTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I wrote a method that looks for all the words in TextPane (named `textContent`) that are the same as the word given in `TextField1`(the word you search for) and it highlights them yellow:

```
private void findAlleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    String search = TextField1.getText();

    try{
        if(!TextField1.getText().isEmpty()){
            while(i != -1){
                    i = textContent.getText().indexOf(search, j);
                if(i == -1)
                    break;
                if(evt.getSource() == findAll || evt.getSource() == findAllButton){
                    textContent.select(i, i + search.length());   
                }
                Color c = Color.YELLOW;
                Style s = textContent.addStyle("TextBackground", null);
                StyleConstants.setBackground(s, c);
                StyledDocument d = textContent.getStyledDocument();
                d.setCharacterAttributes(textContent.getSelectionStart(), textContent.getSelectionEnd() - textContent.getSelectionStart(), textContent.getStyle("TextBackground"), false);
                j = i + search.length();
                index++;
            }
            if (index > 0){
                textContent.grabFocus();
                textContent.setCaretPosition(textContent.getText().indexOf(search, 0) );
                if(evt.getSource() == findAll || evt.getSource() == findAllButton){
                    status.setText("Term: " + TextField1.getText() + ". Number of apperances: " + index);
                } 
            } else {
                textContent.grabFocus();
                if(evt.getSource() == findAll || evt.getSource() == findAllButton){
                    status.setText("Term " + search + " was not found.");
                } 
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        status.setText("Error finding requested term.");
        System.err.print(e);
    }
}
```

Now I am making another method `changeAllActionperformed()` that would  replace ALL of the highlighted words with the word given in `TextField2`. I tried doing that with `textContent.replaceSelection(TextField2.getText());`but the problem is that it puts the new word just in front of the first highighted word and it doesn't even delete it. And what I would like is to delete all highlighted words and replace them all with the new word from `Textfield2`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason it can't be this simple?

```
String replaced = textContent.getText().replace(search, TextField2.getText());
textContent.setText(replaced);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I just didn't know about the existence of the replace() method :)